# Passing the function that returns to OR Operator to something else in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to pick the day flexibility by ideally entering disableDate(1,2,3,4,0) but it doesn't work. Could you help me to make this work, please?

This is the function.

```
const disableDate = (date) => {
  const day = date.day(); 
  return day === 1 || day === 2 || day === 3 || day === 4 || day === 0;
};
```

And this is where the function is passed.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
    adapterLocale="en-gb">
{/* dateAdapter={CustomAdapter} */}
    <StaticDatePicker
    displayStaticWrapperAs="desktop"
    openTo="day"
    value={value}
    **shouldDisableDate={disableDate}**
    minDate={minMonth}
    maxDate={maxMonth}
    // dayOfWeekFormatter={(day) => day.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + day.charAt(1) + days}
    dayOfWeekFormatter={(day) => `${day}`}
    onChange={(newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}/>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I tried to see what's in date and where it comes from but it doesn't come from anywhere. Also, I tried to pass an array to the shouldDisableDate but it didn't work either.

date and typeof date
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do `disableDate(1, 2, 3, 4, 0)` as you'll need to assign a new function to `shouldDisableDate` which would require you to pass in the date to that function.

So, with that in mind, you can take the date from the component property (it's implicitly passed in as the first argument), and use that as the first argument in `disableDate` along with the array/series of days to check. I've used an array for clarity.

A note on the date conversion - it looks like MUI uses [date-io](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/date-io) which is "an abstraction interface" over a variety of different libraries including the native JS date constructor. which means that you can pass it in as the argument to `new Date` and use native Date methods to extract the day.

```
// Pass in the date, and an array of days to check
function disableDate(date, queryArr) {

  // Convert the date, and extract the day
  const day = new Date(date).getDay();

  // Return a true/false if the array includes the day
  return queryArr.includes(day);
};
```

And in the JSX

```
// Take the date from the function and pass it in as the
// first argument to `disableDate`, along with the array
shouldDisableDate={(date) => disableDate(date, [1, 2, 3, 4, 0])}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Andy. I got this error: Uncaught TypeError: date.getDay is not a function

Comment: Ah, ok. Is `date` not a real date then? Based on the documentation I thought it was. I can't test this because I don't have MUI set up. In the function could you do `console.log(date, typeof date)` immediately after the declaration, and we can see what it is, and what type it is. @Taka

Comment: It says it's an object. I'll add the screenshot to the next answer post. Thanks Andy :)

Comment: You should delete that and edit the question with it instead. @Taka. I'll take another look at the documentation.

Comment: OK, I've updated the function. See if that makes a difference. @Taka

Comment: It works! Thank you, Andy.  
Could you explain what this is doing, please? -> new Date(date).getDay();
Where is Date() and getDay() coming from? And what is it?

Comment: From what I can work out `date` is a [date.io](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/date-io) object. You can pass it as an argument to JS's own Date constructor to get a "proper" date, and then `getDay` returns the day number. There's probably a better way of doing it but this seems to work ok.